# Using Next.js Image component is making <title> empty

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

I have a slider component. Within this component I started using next.js `Image` components instead of standard image elements. Since making this switch, I have notice my title tags initially change based on the page correctly however, they become empty once the images render. I confirmed this by inspecting the element. Prior to making the switch to next.js `Image` I did not have this problem and the title tags remained populated based on the page/index. I did some googling and found this issue report [Prevent unsetting title from document](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/3795). I have since removed the title tag from `_document.js` and I am still having this issue. Any other ideas on how to fix this issue?

Here is my component:

```
//ProductSlider.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Image from 'next/image'

class ProductSlider extends Component {
  render() {
    const settings = {
      //my setting here
    };
    let slider_data = this.props.slider_data
    let product_array = []
    for (let product in slider_data) {
      product_array.push(
        <div key={product+'product-slider'}>
          <Image
            src={slider_data[product].image}
            alt={slider_data[product].name}
            priority={true}
            width={'95px'}
            height={'95px'}
            className='product-slide'
          />
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div className="home-slick product-slick">
        <Slider {...settings}>
          {product_array}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ProductSlider.propTypes = {
  slider_data: PropTypes.array,
}

export default ProductSlider
```

_document.js:

```
//_document.js
import Document, { Html, Head, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(sb) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(sb)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon.png" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

I set all titles for each page using this function:

```
function SEO ({ title, description }) {
  return (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang,
      }}>
      <title>{title}</title>
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.png"></link>
      <meta name='description' content={description}/>
    </Helmet>
  )
}
```

Update: I have since discovered that this is caused by `priority={true}` but have not found a solution since I still want priority to be true.